# Redirect page - For tracker plugin on Tiki

Tags: plugins, tracker, tiki-wiki

I am trying to pass parameters into the redirect section of the Tracker plugin. I understand that while using the Tracker plugin, you can redirect to a specific Tiki page, but I want to redirect user to a tracker item ID instead i.e.../tiki/itemxx. How do I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like the documentation [here](https://doc.tiki.org/plugintracker#Parameters) doesn't quite cover this currently (please update it with a working example if you can, thanks)

You need to set the url parameter in the plugin to

```
url="tiki-view_tracker_item.php?itemId"
```

Sadly this doesn't seem to work with the *sefurl* itemxxx syntax currently.

Comment: If you really need the _itemxx_ syntax you could maybe do that by creating a wiki page with [Redirect wiki-plugin](https://doc.tiki.org/PluginRedirect) and [Argument Variables](https://doc.tiki.org/Wiki+Argument+Variables) enabled.

On page with Tracker wiki-plugin: `url="RedirectToTrackerView?itemId"`
On page RedirectToTrackerView: `{redirect url="item{{itemId}}"}`

Comment: Thanks @jonnybradley Yes, this didn't work with the itemxxx syntax until another developer in-house commented out the feedback part of the code. In his words: "I found the problem. The error occurs when in the tracker plugin before redirecting there are some codes for showing successful feedback. As I commented the feedback code, everything worked fine. "